# Многопоточность вкупе с многоядерностью

Tags: многопоточность, ядро

Проводил массивные вычисления логарифма и мерял их скорость на разном количестве потоков на 4-хядерном процессоре. Результаты натолкнули на вопрос: почему скорость выполнения на 1 и 2 потоках одинаковая я еще понимаю (хотя может неправильно, поясните тоже). Но на 4 и 8 потоках тоже одинаковая (но выше, чем на 1 и 2, очевидно). Почему?

А также еще вопрос, почему скорость вычисления на 3 потоках гораздо ниже, чем даже на 1-2?

Comment: В ОС общего назначения постоянно висит в работе 100500 процессов и потоков, так что о производительности можно говорить только В СРЕДНЕМ. Опять же алгоритм планировщика в винде неизвестен. Попробуйте поднять приоритеты Ваших потоков вплоть до полной блокировки всех остальных процессов и даже процессов ввода-вывода и сравните время.

Comment: `почему скорость вычисления на 3 потоках гораздо ниже, чем даже на 1-2? ` а вдруг это из-за неудачной реализации распараллеливания?

Comment: Без знания деталей (алгоритм, реализация, код измерения времени выполнения, ОС, входные данные) обсуждение особого смысла не имеет

Answer (score 0):

> на 4-хядерном процессоре

Что в вашем понимании 4х ядерный? не стоит считать виртуальные ядра за "ядра".(гипертрединг), они ускоряют далеко не все задачи и не всегда.

> почему скорость выполнения на 1 и 2 потоках одинаковая я еще понимаю

Скорей всего нет, причин может быть масса один из вариантов оба потока запущены на одном ядре, второй вариант - код неверно распаралеленн

> Но на 4 и 8 потоках тоже одинаковая (но выше, чем на 1 и 2, очевидно).

А с чего бы 4 и 8 потоков выполнялись с разной скоростью на 4х(скорее всего двух) ядрах? на самом деле на таком малом кол-ве потоков вы не заметите разницы, но чем больше потоков(по отношению к кол-ву ядер) - тем медленней они будут выполнятся.

> А также еще вопрос, почему скорость вычисления на 3 потоках гораздо ниже, чем даже на 1-2?

Опять возможно очень много вариантов, сейчас вижу гадание на кофейной гуще...
Вы не привели ни железа на котором проводите тесты, ни код которым тестируете, ни даже настроек потоков.